# Android - Bandwidth Monitoring for a specific IP address in LAN network

Tags: android, shell, iptables

My android device acted as DHCP and DNS Server (Hotspot android). As far as I look up. Because android is Linux Based OS, so I use iptables to monitor the bandwidth for a specific ip in my LAN (Ex:192.168.10.10). Here is what I've done:

Create the chain

```
.iptables -N LAPTOP-DOWNLOAD
```

Monitor this IP

```
.iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.10.10 -j LAPTOP-DOWNLOAD
```

But here is what the problem is. It errors out in my chain

```
.netent* getnetbyaddr(uint32_t, int)(3) is not implemented on Android
```

I guess because the android kernel itself won't support monitoring specific IP destination. I've tried :

```
.iptables -A FORWARD -j LAPTOP-DOWNLOAD
```

And It works, it doesn't give me any errors. Anyhow I can fix this. Thanks in advance